# Universal Windows c#: Media Capture Webcam Live Stream

Tags: c#, uwp, media, live-streaming, uwp-xaml

i try to livestream the webcam over network (UWP, c#)

I tried yet: Recording a 2 second Video using MediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync (send the stream over network) and repeat this. Ofcourse this is a bad solution, as everytime i use StopRecordAsync, i loose like half a second, and on the other side it looks like a huge lagg.

There must be a solution without calling StopRecordAsync every 2 seconds. How can i send the video data over the network while still recording?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I think the [Real-time communication sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication) might be what you want. This sample shows how to use the low latency feature to enable real-time communication applications.

This sample uses the Media Extension feature to add functionality to the Microsoft Media Foundation pipeline. For more info on creating a Media Foundation media extension in Windows Store app, see Walkthrough: [Creating a Windows Store app using WRL and Media Foundation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=309355) and the [Media extension sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=241427).